# Is it possible to get a data from an excel file from a particular table if I have two tables in one worksheet using EPPlus?

Tags: epplus

I have a file that contains a few tables on one worksheet. How do I get data from a particular table using EPPlus? thanks a lot

I looked through samples and questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference tables by index or by name using this:

```
var x = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"c:\FooFolder\Bin_Template.xlsx"));
var table = x.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Tables["Table1"];
```